# Is there any way to preserve recent keyboard activity in case something accidentally gets deleted?

Tags: macos

I sometimes find things I have written in online forms get deleted without the chance for recovery. Is there any way, on an iPad for example, or Mac, that there could be a mechanism recording recent keyboard activity, so you could recover short-term lost written text?

Comment: Built in?  No.  What you’re referring to is called a keylogger.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd still like a key logger here are some choices. There are many keyloggers that do much more than logging the keystrokes. Most have many more features but these can be turned off if you're only interested in keylogging. Some highly rated yet easy to use keyloggers are [Aobo Mac Keylogger](https://www.easemon.com/aobo-mac-os-x-keylogger.html),  [Perfect Keylogger for Mac](https://mac-keylogger.org), and  [Refog Keylogger for Mac](https://www.refog.com/mac-keylogger.html). Be careful with these because they will log your passwords unless properly set up. Aobo Key Logger is a Mac-only app. These were obtained from [this site](https://medium.com/@janetcpatterson/top-5-user-approved-keyloggers-for-mac-cc3f096d426b) that rates 5 keyloggers.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are really bad for this. Only the most advanced sites like this one have undo and they have to do it in JavaScript and that can be buggy, heavy handed and leak private information in plain text.

It’s much better to do your authoring in an app that supports arbitrary undo on macOS and iOS. Since these OS support multitasking and split view windows and have superb copy/paste functionality in the native apps,  you can then copy your completed information and not need to change the web pages and forms you are using.

Even better, you can use third party apps as needed if Apple’s editors aren’t the right tool for making form entry better than a web browser (which is still a very low bar TBH these days, very low)